# SQL Pivot as a sub query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the below code:

```
DECLARE @lcid INT 
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME=@10
DECLARE @enddate DATETIME=@11
DECLARE @PitchJobTypeId INT
DECLARE @ClientInvestmentJobTypeId INT
DECLARE @AdministrationJobTypeId INT

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #data


DECLARE @Billablejob TABLE(
id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Jobid INT)


DECLARE @Department table(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
DepartmentId INT)

IF @10 > @11
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Error in date selection' AS 'Error';
    GOTO ExitSp;
END



INSERT INTO @Billablejob(Jobid)
SELECT distinct s.Element FROM dbo.Split(@30,',') AS s

Insert into @Department(DepartmentId)
SELECT distinct s.Element FROM dbo.Split(@5,',') AS s
IF EXISTS(SELECT '' FROM @Department AS d WHERE d.DepartmentId=0) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT '' FROM @Department AS d) BEGIN
    DELETE FROM @Department
    INSERT INTO @Department(DepartmentId)
    SELECT rsa.AfdID FROM RessSelAfd AS rsa --INNER JOIN @comp c ON c.compid=rsa.SelID  
END

IF @20 IS NULL SET @20=0

CREATE TABLE #data(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[Name]  nvarchar(MAX),
[Employee Type] nvarchar(MAX),
[Basic Time] money,
[Used Time] MONEY,
[Holiday] MONEY,
[Recovery] MONEY,
[Illness] MONEY,
[Billable Time] MONEY,
[Non Billable Time] MONEY,
[Pitch Time] MONEY,
[Internal Time] MONEY,
[Used Time2] MONEY,
[Max Billable Hours] MONEY,
[Available Hours] MONEY,
[Office Hours %] INT,
[Billable %] INT,
[Non Billable %] INT,
[Pitch %] INT,
[Internal %] INT,
[Billable Target %] INT,
[Variance to Target %] INT,
[Department] NVARCHAR(max),
[Job Role] NVARCHAR(max),
[Market] NVARCHAR(max),
EmpId INT,
DepartmentId INT,
JobRoleId INT,
MarketId INT,
IsActive BIT,
Hiredate DATETIME,
Expirydate DATETIME,
EmployeeType INT
)

IF @10>@11 BEGIN
SELECT 'Date selection error' Error
GOTO ExitSp
END

SELECT @PitchJobTypeId = sj.JobTypeID FROM SysJobtype AS sj WHERE sj.JobtypeNavn='Pitch'

IF @PitchJobTypeId IS NULL BEGIN
SELECT 'Jobtype ''Pitch'' not found' Error
GOTO ExitSp
END

SELECT @ClientInvestmentJobTypeId = sj.JobTypeID FROM SysJobtype AS sj WHERE sj.JobtypeNavn='Client Investment'

IF @ClientInvestmentJobTypeId IS NULL BEGIN
SELECT 'Jobtype ''Client Investment'' not found' Error
GOTO ExitSp
END

SELECT @AdministrationJobTypeId = sj.JobTypeID FROM SysJobtype AS sj WHERE sj.JobtypeNavn='Administration'

IF @AdministrationJobTypeId IS NULL BEGIN
SELECT 'Jobtype ''Administration'' not found' Error
GOTO ExitSp
END




SELECT @lcid=InterfaceLcid FROM ress WHERE ressid=@UserId

INSERT INTO #data( empid,[Name],[Billable Target %],[JobRoleId],[Job Role],DepartmentId,MarketId,IsActive,Hiredate,Expirydate,EmployeeType,[Employee Type])
SELECT emp.empid,EmpName,(SELECT TOP 1 ehp.ProfitTarget*100 FROM EmpHrsPrice AS ehp WHERE ehp.EmpId = emp.empid AND ehp.ValidFrom <= @enddate ORDER BY ehp.ValidFrom desc),emppost.PostId,

(SELECT ISNULL(nullif(ActLang.ActTxt,''), Act.ActTxt)
    FROM    Act 
        LEFT JOIN ActLang 
            ON Act.AID = ActLang.Aid
            AND ActLang.LCID=@LCID
    WHERE   Act.AID=emp.aid),emp.DepartmentId,emp.CompId,emp.IsActive,emp.Hiredate,emp.Expirydate,emp.EmployTypeId,CASE WHEN et.enumval=1 OR et.enumval=2 THEN 'Permanent' ELSE 'Freelance' END FROM emp 
INNER JOIN ress ON ress.RessID=emp.EmpId 
INNER JOIN @Department AS d ON d.DepartmentId = Emp.DepartmentId
LEFT JOIN emppost ON emp.PostId=emppost.PostId
LEFT JOIN EnumTable(467) AS et ON et.EnumVal=emp.EmployTypeId
WHERE (IsActive=1 OR (Expirydate>=@startdate and Expirydate<=@enddate)) AND (CASE WHEN emp.EmployTypeId=2 THEN 1 ELSE emp.EmployTypeId END=@20 OR @20=0) AND Ress.UserAcountType<>5

UPDATE d SET d.Department=rsa.AfdNavn FROM #data d INNER JOIN RessSelAfd AS rsa ON d.DepartmentId=rsa.AfdID

UPDATE d SET d.Market=comp.CompName FROM #data d INNER JOIN comp ON d.MarketId=comp.compid

UPDATE d SET d.[Basic Time]=data.HrsNorm FROM #data d INNER JOIN
(SELECT cap.ResId,Sum(ISNULL(Cap.HrsNorm,0)+ISNULL(Cap.HrsHoli,0)) AS HrsNorm FROM cap INNER JOIN #data d ON d.empid=cap.ResId AND CAST(DayDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
GROUP BY cap.ResId) data ON d.EmpId=data.ResId

UPDATE d SET d.[Used Time]=data.UsedHours FROM #data d INNER JOIN
(SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours FROM TimeReg AS tr WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
and reghrs IS NOT null
GROUP BY tr.EmpId ) data ON d.EmpId=data.EmpId

UPDATE d SET [Basic Time]=[Used Time],d.[Billable Target %]=100 FROM #data d WHERE EmployeeType=3

UPDATE d SET [Basic Time]=ISNULL([Basic Time],0),[Used Time]=ISNULL([Used Time],0) FROM #data d 

UPDATE d
SET d.Holiday = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN RessFerie AS rf ON rf.RecId=tr.EmpHoliRecId
    INNER JOIN AbsenceCode AS ac ON ac.Id=rf.AbsenceID
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID    
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND cust.CustTypeId=5 AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId AND ac.Descr<>'Recovery Day'
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.Recovery = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN RessFerie AS rf ON rf.RecId=tr.EmpHoliRecId
    INNER JOIN AbsenceCode AS ac ON ac.Id=rf.AbsenceID
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID    
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND cust.CustTypeId=5 AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId AND ac.Descr='Recovery Day'
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.Illness = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND cust.CustTypeId=6 AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.[Billable Time] = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID
    LEFT JOIN @Billablejob AS bj ON job.JobID=bj.Jobid
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND (job.DebitFlg=1 OR bj.Jobid IS NOT NULL) AND (cust.CustTypeId=1 OR cust.CustTypeId=2) AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId AND job.JobTypeID<>@ClientInvestmentJobTypeId AND job.JobTypeID<>@AdministrationJobTypeId
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.[Non Billable Time] = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID
    LEFT JOIN @Billablejob AS bj ON job.JobID=bj.Jobid
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND ((bj.Jobid IS NULL and job.DebitFlg=0 AND (cust.CustTypeId=1 OR cust.CustTypeId=2) AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId AND job.JobTypeID<>@AdministrationJobTypeId)  OR job.JobTypeID=@ClientInvestmentJobTypeId)
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.[Pitch Time] = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND tr.EmpHoliRecId IS NULL AND job.JobTypeID=@PitchJobTypeId
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.[Internal Time] = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND tr.EmpHoliRecId IS NULL AND (((cust.CustTypeId=3 OR cust.CustTypeId=4) AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId AND job.JobTypeID<>@ClientInvestmentJobTypeId) OR job.JobTypeID=@AdministrationJobTypeId)
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d SET d.[Used Time2]=isnull(d.[Used Time],0)-isnull(d.Recovery,0) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Max Billable Hours]=ISNULL(d.[Used Time2],0)-ISNULL(d.Holiday,0)-ISNULL(d.Illness,0) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Available Hours]=ISNULL(d.[Basic Time],0)-ISNULL(d.Holiday,0)-ISNULL(d.Illness,0) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Office Hours %]=CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Available Hours],0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE d.[Max Billable Hours]/d.[Available Hours]*100 END AS INT) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Billable %]=CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Available Hours],0)=0 THEN CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Billable Time],0)=0 THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ELSE d.[Billable Time]/d.[Available Hours]*100 END AS INT) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Non Billable %]=CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Available Hours],0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE d.[Non Billable Time]/d.[Available Hours]*100 END AS INT) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Pitch %]=CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Available Hours],0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE d.[Pitch Time]/d.[Available Hours]*100 END AS INT) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Internal %]=CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Available Hours],0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE d.[Internal Time]/d.[Available Hours]*100 END AS INT) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Variance to Target %]=ISNULL(d.[Billable %],0)-ISNULL(d.[Billable Target %],0) FROM #data d


SELECT d.Name,
       d.[Employee Type],
       d.[Basic Time],
       d.[Used Time] AS [Total Time posted],
       isnull(d.Holiday,0)+isnull(d.Illness,0) [Absence],
       d.Recovery,
       d.[Billable Time],
       d.[Non Billable Time],
       d.[Pitch Time],
       d.[Internal Time],
       isnull(d.[Used Time2],0) AS [Used Time],
       d.[Max Billable Hours],
       d.[Available Hours],
       CAST(d.[Office Hours %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Office Hours %],
       CAST(d.[Billable %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Billable %],
       CAST(d.[Non Billable %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Non Billable %],
       CAST(d.[Pitch %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Pitch %],
       CAST(d.[Internal %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Internal %],
       CAST(d.[Billable Target %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Billable Target %],
       CAST(d.[Variance to Target %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Variance to Target %],
       d.Department,
       d.[Job Role],
       d.Market
       FROM #data d

ExitSp:
```

That produces a large table containing data similar to below:

[image]

I would like to include a Pivot sub query to wrap up various elements of the above original query but cannot seem to get this to work.

I have tried including the below at the beginning of my original script::

```
SELECT [Department], [Employee Type],[Basic Time]
FROM
(
```

and then:

```
    ) As SourceTable
PIVOT
    (
    SUM ([Basic Time])
    FOR [[Basic Time]] IN ([Employee Type])
    ) AS PivotTable
```

At the end but with no luck?

Can anyone help out in the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify each possible value for `Employee Type` as column names, for example:

```
SELECT Name, Department, Permanent AS BasicTime_Permanent, Freelance AS BasicTime_Freelance
FROM
(
    SELECT Name, Department, [Employee Type], [Basic Time]
    FROM (
        ...
    ) x
) As SourceTable
PIVOT (
    SUM ([Basic Time]) 
    FOR [Employee Type] IN (Permanent, Freelance)
) AS PivotTable
```

See the [example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017#complex-pivot-example).

However, it seems you need multiple PIVOT queries (one for `[Basic Time]`, one for `[Total time posted]`, etc) that should be later joined together (with outer joins). It looks to me as too much trouble for a result that would be too wide anyway.